# Make smooth curves in GCode

Tags: g-code, cad

I am getting started with GCode, and I don't know all the commands. Is there a way to smooth a path between two points? I wrote a program which makes GCode from a silhouette. Problem is, when it looks at the individual pixels, its path becomes a bit choppy. Is there a command that will make a more natural path. Attached is a close up picture of the path simulation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curves are normally approximated with straight-line segments. However, some firmwares (e.g. Marlin) support arc commands. See:

[Marlin: Controlled Arc Move](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G002-G003.html)
[RepRap: Controlled Arc Move](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G2_.26_G3:_Controlled_Arc_Move)

Note that the RepRap Wiki is not always accurate in its list of supported commands.